# XOrg: High CPU usage with Multibutton mouse

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, xorg

I have multibutton programmable mouse (roccat tyon) that have its extra button mapped to keyboard keys in such way, that the mouse acts as a keyboard when these are pressed (eg, the logic is within the mouse, not the driver, mouse appears as a standard HUD device without any special driver)

When I try to use them, I get a frozen XOrg, where xfwm4 uses 100% cpu. Then its ok until I try to use keyboard. Then ok until I switch between mouse and keyboard again. These freezes are short after bootup, but longer everytime they occur. As if xorg could not accept key presses from two different keyboards connected at the same time and kept switching between them in some expensive way.

Can I overcome this behavior by some config or automated restarting of some service?

I run XUbuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Please edit the question and add. What version of Ubuntu? How were the buttons mapped to the keys, the exact command and how you configured it. Please use edit and not answer in comments.